# Running node in systemctl: child_process.fork throwing ENOENT

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, systemctl

I have a NodeJS program managed by systemctl. Up until recently, **this has been working** but I did an upgrade of the system (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS) recently and I'm not sure why making a call to child_process.fork throws ENOENT for a version of node installed via nvm.

My setup:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- NodeJS installed with nvm, under a non-privileged account `nodebb`
- [My systemctl service](https://gist.github.com/bdharrington7/2599927d41d30f11900f2099b8d8fc64)
- [The platform](https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB)
- The [plugin](https://github.com/panascais/nodebb-plugin-camo) throwing the error at [this call](https://github.com/panascais/nodebb-plugin-camo/blob/d275d15a5a3a0a762b5493040970bd75b499735f/src/lib/server.es6#L25)

This is the exact error causing my process to crash:

```
29/10 16:53:17 [9891] - error:  Error: spawn /usr/share/nginx/nodebb/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.5/bin/node ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:189:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:363:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:511:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:425:17)
```

And the binary is indeed in that location, and permissions are correct (parent folders are accessible by the `nodebb` user):

`nodebb@server:~$ /usr/share/nginx/nodebb/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.5/bin/node -v
v4.8.5`